# Не работает обновление Composer

Tags: windows, composer

При обновлении `composer` или установке пакетов выдает подобную ошибку:

```
composer self-update
```

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream

Я так понимаю, невозможно подключиться к `getcomposer.org` и к репозиториям.
Такая же проблема что на компе, что на ноутбуке.
Любая команда требующая подключения к другим сайтам выдает подобную ошибку.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: сделай с ново  `composer install` вместо `composer update`

Comment: любая команда подключения к внешним сайтам выдает ошибки

Comment: у тебя `linux` или `windows` ?

Comment: у меня стоит windows

Comment: а любая какая команда например еще? вот например `ping`  работает или нет?

Comment: И после чего у тебя не работают команды?

Comment: ping работает, при диагностике выдает вот такое:

Comment: Попробуй откат сделать ՝windows՝․

Comment: Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded
Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: FAIL
Missing pubkey for tags verification
Missing pubkey for dev verification
Run composer self-update --update-keys

Comment: добавьте composer.json

Comment: Дополните вопрос - какие команды вызываются, какая ОС?

Comment: windows 8 и windows10, даже обновление композера через composer self-update не работает. ping getcomposer.org не работает всетаки (но через браузер захожу)

Comment: [Поправте вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/687918/edit) с учётом комментариев.

Comment: "но через браузер захожу" возможно ваш интернет работает через прокси-сервер, композер об этом прокси ничего не знает

Comment: Спасибки за направление! Не с одного браузера на https://getcomposer.org зайти не могу, а вот с оперы которая работает через прокси спокойно захожу, наверное где-то блокируется этот сайт.